Center card in Bootstrap
I am trying to center the card but its not getting centered properly, im a beginner so im not sure what to do.

</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-12">
        <div class="card bg-card col-12">
          <div class="card-body text-center">
            <img class="rounded-circle mt-3" src="avatar-jessica.jpeg" alt="" style="height: 100px; max-width: auto;">
            <div>
              <h5 class="text-white mt-2">Jessica Randall</h5>
              <p class="text-green">London, United Kingdom</p>
              <p class="text-white">"Front-end developer and avid reader."</p>
            </div>
            <div class="mx-auto col-9 d-grid gap-3">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">GitHub</a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Frontend Mentor</a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">LinkedIn</a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Twitter</a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary mb-3" href="#" role="button">Instagram</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

In the foto you can see how far I got
Ive looked up on many pages but I didn't find a solution, i want the card to be in the center of the screen.
this is my goal

You'll add justify-content-center class on the row element.

I would also consider adding a ending double quote on the container element.

I did all that but stillnot working now its looking even worser...

now i deleted the d-flex and the align-item-center an now its in the middle, but onley horizontal

@SiCaPfe, unless you have other CSS for the card element, you don't need the col-12 class. If you are wanting vertical alignment, add align-items-center to the row.



.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    /* align-items: center; this will also align the card in center horizontally */

}



try justifying content to center in the container div as it is your main parent div It will center your whole card in the middle of widow screen
